# codenameone keypad interact with menu

Tags: button, menu, key, codenameone

How can I figure out what keys of keypad pressed in non touch devices. As you know I want to map keys to my application menu that each of its items is `Button`.

Is it a good way to watch what keys pressed and map it to menu items (or do something when specific key pressed)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Form` class you have an `addKeyListener` method which you can use to track key presses, a key code you receive via the action performed method is an int containing the ASCII value of the key e.g. `'a'/'A'` in a qwerty device or `'1'` in a keypad device.

You can also derive form and override `keyReleased` although that isn't as generic.

Comment: How can I user this method? Is any sample exist?

Comment: I search and I find out I must invoke it for all of keys for example addKeyListener('1', listener); and addKeyListener('2', listener); . Is it true?

Comment: Thanks. And I remove listener by invoke removeKeyListener('1', listener) on deinitialize method of form.